# Can some explain the difference with Xcode SceneDelegate vs App file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have created an app for iOS in 2020, where when I started a brand new app with Swift and SwiftUI there would be two specific files:

```
1. SceneDelegate and 
2. ContentView
```

I have since downloaded Xcode and was looking to update my current app and noticed that the two base files now are:

```
1. <App Name>App and
2. ContentView
```

Why was the change made? And has that changed any behaviors?

Would I be able to "copy and paste" my code from the "old" app to the "new" app version? or has there been architectural changes that need to be accounted for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change was made because of the new `App` protocol:

- https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/06/23/what-is-new-in-swiftui/
- https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10037/

The amount of changes required depends on the complexity of your SceneDelegate. You can use the Scene type's [`onChange(of:perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scene/onchange(of:perform:)) method to handle events you would've previously handled in your SceneDelegate:

https://www.iosdevie.com/p/swiftui-replace-appdelegate-scenedelegate

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
     @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
 
     var body: some Scene {
         WindowGroup {
             ContentView()
         }
         .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
             if phase == .background {
                //perform cleanup
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: `You can use the Scene type's onChange(of:perform:) method to handle events you would've previously handled in your SceneDelegate`
What if you need the SceneDelegate for 'quick actions' or 'launch with file'? SceneDelegate's windowScene(_:performActionFor:completionHandler:) serves as the entry point for 'quick actions' and similarly, there's another one for handling 'launch with file'. In that case, should I have both the SceneDelegate and scenePhase?